# How To Replace First HTML <strong></strong> Tag in PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a text string in PHP:

```
<strong> MOST </strong> of you may have a habit of wearing socks while sleeping. 
<strong> Wear socks while sleeping to prevent cracking feet</strong>
<strong> Socks helps to relieve sweaty feet</strong>
```

We can see, the first strong tag is

```
<strong> MOST </strong>
```

I want to remove the first strong tag, and make word inside of it to ucwords (first letter capitalized). Result like this

```
Most of you may have a habit of wearing socks while sleeping. 
<strong> Wear socks while sleeping to prevent cracking feet</strong>
<strong> Socks helps to relieve sweaty feet</strong>
```

I have tried with explode function, but it seem not like what I want. Here is my code

```
<?php
$text = "<strong>MOST</strong> of you may have a habit of wearing socks while sleeping. <strong> Wear socks while sleeping to prevent cracking feet</strong>. <strong> Socks helps to relieve sweaty feet</strong>";
$context = explode('</strong>',$text);
$context = ucwords(str_replace('<strong>','',strtolower($context[0]))).$context[1];
echo $context;
?>
```

My code only result

```
Most of you may have a habit of wearing socks while sleeping. <strong> Wear socks while sleeping to prevent cracking feet
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix your code by using the optional *limit* argument of `explode`:

```
$context = explode("</strong>",$text,2);
```

However, it would be better as:

```
$context = preg_replace_callback("(<strong>(.*?)</strong>)",function($a) {return ucfirst($a[1]);},$text);
```

Comment: +1 For using the `preg_replace_callback` function. But it should be `return ucfirst(strtolower($a[1]));` because the first match 'MOST' is all caps, so you need to lower it first, then `ucfirst` it. Also, you need to pass in the 4th argument to `preg_replace_callback` - limit as 1, as the question only wants to remove the first `strong` tag.

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked for a solution in PHP, but I don't think showing you a CSS solution would hurt:

**HTML**

```
<p><strong>Most</strong> of you may have a habit of wearing socks while sleeping.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p strong:first-child {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Unless there's a specific reason for using PHP, I think it's simply complicating something that should be easy. Using CSS reduces server load and leaves styling where it should be.

**UPDATE:** [Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/DHBrd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This would make sense:

```
preg_replace("<strong>(.*?)</strong>", "$1", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This provides [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback);

```
$s = '<strong> MOST </strong> of you may have a habit of wearing socks while sleeping.
      <strong> Wear socks while sleeping to prevent cracking feet</strong>
      <strong> Socks helps to relieve sweaty feet</strong>';
$s = preg_replace_callback('~<strong>(.*?)</strong>~i', function($m){
    return ucfirst(strtolower(trim($m[1])));
}, $s, 1);
print $s;
```

Out;

```
Most of you may have a habit of wearing socks while sleeping.
<strong> Wear socks while sleeping to prevent cracking feet</strong>
<strong> Socks helps to relieve sweaty feet</strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with @thordarson his answer doesn't change your content which to me is better. Because your issue is basically a layout issue. This my adapted version from his answer. The difference is that you first restate the strong text back to normal format. Then you capitalize the first letter.

```
   strong {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    strong:first-letter {
        font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DHBrd/1/)